# Presta shop install without demodata

Tags: installation, prestashop

I downloaded Prestashop from the webpage version 1.6.0.6.
In the installproccess at 56%, it gives me an error; the demodata can't be installed.

How can I install this ps-version without this data?

Answer (score 2):

Found that installer try to download a fixtures.zip file, which is a blank page.

ex url: http://api.prestashop.com/fixtures/fr/3/fixtures.zip

Add `return true;` in file install/models/install.php line 667...

```
        /**
     * PROCESS : installFixtures
     * Install fixtures (E.g. demo products)
     */
    public function installFixtures($entity = null, array $data = array())
    {
            return true;
            $fixtures_path = _PS_INSTALL_FIXTURES_PATH_.'fashion/';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem happened to be with file\folder permissions (though I even tried to set permissions to 777 to all files and folders as they say in documentation, but installation just kept failing). 
 
Started to work when I unzipped files on local computer, then in sftp manager changed options so when contents were pushed to server they got 664 permissions for files and 775 for folders. 
I've tried 3 installation in a row on different servers and this method worked just fine. 
Hope this'll help.